# set and get date and time in localStorage in react datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```reactjs
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

class Date extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      startDate: "",
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {

    let startDate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Date") || "");
 {});

    this.setState({
        startDate
    });
  }
  handleChange(date) {
    localStorage.setItem("Date", JSON.stringify(date));
    this.setState({
      startDate: date,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <DatePicker
            className="date"
            selected={this.state.startDate}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            showTimeSelect
            timeFormat="HH:mm"
            timeIntervals={20}
            timeCaption="time"
            dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy / h:mm"
            placeholderText="Select Date and Time"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(Date);
```

When I select date and time from datepicker then pass date and time value of `handleChange` function as a parameter date. date parameter have the value of date and time and I am trying to set this value in `localStorage` but when I get data from local storage, it shows below error...

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your question and fix up your code? I tried but I'm unsure of what you're trying to do here. Also include what "errors" you're getting

Comment: i edit my Question. plez resolve my error..........

Comment: I don't know `react-datepicker` but I assume you have to give it a valid date and you seem to be giving it an empty string at the first run no? What is the object you're storing in `localStorage` right now?

Comment: i am storing date in "localStorage", because i want get this date again from "localStorage" when refresh my "page" or "state".........

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple errors in your code. Parsing an empty string, storing empty string in `startingDate` causing DatePicker to get Invalid Date. Also change your class name to something other than `Date` as its predefined Class name in JavaScript. Try below code

```
class DateComponent extends Component
...
componentDidMount() {
    let startDate = localStorage.getItem("Date") ? new Date(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Date"))) : "";
    this.setState({
      startDate: startDate
    });
  }
...
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(DateComponent);
```

Comment: this answer is not working and showing the same error

Comment: The actual problem with your code is your class name. Please do not use predefined classnames. Can you please rename your class name to something else like 'class DateComponent extends Component'